# RecurrenceTable for computing Required Minimum Distributions from an IRA

Tags: difference-equations

Here is a list of required minimum distributions from an IRA based on IRS published life expectancy tables for a particular age

```
    rmd={5.12821, .34759, .58659, .84795, .13497, .45161, .75676, .09220, .46269}
```

One must withdraw the particular portion shown for subsequent years. The rate is applied to the value of the fund at prior year end (beginning with a starting balance). Assume the fund grows monotonically at 3% per year. Each distribution is the prior year end balance times 1.03 less the current year distribution (calculated on the prior year) times the particular rmd for that year. One would think a `RecurrenceTable` would be just the ticket but it does not like `Part` in the arguments to single out the particular rmd rate for a certain year. The answer in Excel is straightforward assuming no value change in the first year
[image: Spreadsheet]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want `FoldList`.

```
rmd = {5.12821, 5.34759, 5.58659, 5.84795, 6.13497, 6.45161, 6.75676, 7.09220, 7.46269}/100.
ints = Prepend[ConstantArray[0.03, Length[rmd] - 1], 0]
bals = FoldList[#1*#2 &, 100, 1 + ints - rmd]
dists = Most[bals]*rmd
```